# AbsoluteLayout Bounds Don't Position Correctly for Sizes Larger than 50

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have an AbsoluteLayout where I'm trying to embed a BoxView.

I assign the BoxView's positioning via:

```
AbsoluteLayout.SetLayoutFlags(WordThrottle, AbsoluteLayoutFlags.PositionProportional);
AbsoluteLayout.SetLayoutBounds(WordThrottle, new Rectangle(1.0, 1.0, 70, 70));
```

But when I inspect the result, I get this:
[image]

Rather than this:

[image]

(The second image is with size 50x50)

Sizes larger than 50 also don't seem to make any difference in size on screen. What am I missing here?

EDIT: Here's the declaration of WordThrottle:

```
<AbsoluteLayout BackgroundColor="Green">
    <mr:BoxView x:Name="WordThrottle" Color="Yellow" WidthRequest="50" HeightRequest="50" VerticalOptions="Start" HorizontalOptions="Start" />
</AbsoluteLayout>
```

Comment: How is WordThrottle declared?

Comment: `yourAbsoluteLayout.Padding=0;
yourView.Margin=0;`

Comment: Just updated the post with declaration of Wordthrottle

Comment: I'm an idiot - I forgot that I set the WidthRequest and HeightRequest to 50..

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
AbsoluteLayout.SetLayoutFlags(WordThrottle, AbsoluteLayoutFlags.PositionProportional);
AbsoluteLayout.SetLayoutBounds(WordThrottle, new Rectangle(1f, 1f, AbsoluteLayout.AutoSize, AbsoluteLayout.AutoSize));
```